# intellisense в VisualStudio 2019 не видит члены вложенного класса шаблона

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

[image: Сообщение о том, что члены не доступны.]

При попытке обратиться к членам вложенного класса через точку или "->" intellisense не даёт подсказок. Проект работает, но название членов приходится прописывать вручную, без подсказок. Подскажите, как исправить, пожалуйста!

```
template <typename T, typename K>
class RBST
{
private:

    struct Node {
    public:
        T value;
        K key;
        Node* left = nullptr;
        Node* right = nullptr;
        Node* parent = nullptr;
        int subtrees_quantity = 0;
    } *head = nullptr;
public:
void add(const T, const K);

};

template<typename T, typename K>
void RBST<T, K>::add(const T value, const K key)
{
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = new Node();
        head->
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Кусочек кода помог бы прояснить проблему. Как говорится, почитайте о том, что такое [mcve], а то не ясно совсем как можно это повторить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следует указать intellisense пробные параметры для шаблона (в тулбарчике с `<T>` есть выпадающий список со списком инстанцирований, а справа есть кнопка редактировать для указания произвольных параметров).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]